# Ошибка "переменная не инициализирована"

Tags: java

Улучшенная программа с временами года

```
class Switch {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int month = 4;
 String season;
 switch (month) {

  case 12:
  case 1:
  case 2:
   season = "Zima";
   break;

  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
   season = "Vesna";
   break;

  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8:
   season = "Leto";
   break;

  case 9:
  case 10:
  case 11:
   season = "Osen";
   break;

  default:
   System.out.println("NOT");
 }
 System.out.println(" " + season + " ");
 }
}
```

Comment: Суровый такой `switch` )

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за того, что значение переменная season получает, не совсем явно для компилятора. т.е. он на перед не может знать какое из условий будет использовано, для задания значения этой переменной, и он допускает, что такое "условие" могло остаться и не выполненным, и переменная season так и осталась без значения. Что бы компилятор не ругался, можете при создании просто указать какое то дефолтное значение, пускай зима:

```
String season = "Zima";
```

Comment: Сергей,подскажите как стать таким "въехавшим в тему как вы!!!"?
Как вы учились программированию?Я хочу стать хорошим программистом!

Comment: Или просто `String season = null;`

Comment: @vikkingg :  
<code><pre>
String[] sezon={"vesna", "leto", "osen", "zima"};
if (month<3) month+=12;
String season=sezon[(int) (month-3)/3];
</code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в одном из вариантов исхода switch переменная не будет инициализирована - в default. Компилятор видит возможность такой ошибки времени исполнения и пытается ее предотвратить. Чтобы компилятор не ругался, надо сделать либо как предолжил [@Kozlov Sergei](/users/3133/kozlov-sergei), т.е. инициализировать при объявлении,  либо присвоить ей какое-то значение в варианте default.

Answer (score 1):

мда, по этой же причине хотя бы один return в if-else (при использовании в методе) нужно использовать или вне блока, или для "всех остальных случаев" (else{...}, без if)